# Good reference for studying operads?

Tags: reference-request, operads

Can you, please, recommend a good text about algebraic operads?

I know the main one, namely, [Loday, Vallette "Algebraic operads"](http://www-irma.u-strasbg.fr/~loday/PAPERS/LodayVallette.pdf). But it is very big and there is no way you can read it fast. Also there are notes by [Vallette "Algebra+Homotopy=Operad"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.3245), but they don't have much information and are too combinatorial. So what I am looking for is a pretty concise introduction to the theory of algebraic operads, that will be more algebraic then combinatorial, and that will give enough information to actually start working with operads.

Thank you very much for your help!

**Edit**: I have also found this interesting paper [Modules and Morita Theorem for Operads](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9906063v2.pdf) by Kapranov--Manin. Maybe it's a bit too concise for the first time reading about operads, but it has a lot of really nice examples and theorems.

There are also [notes](http://folk.uib.no/nmajv/Operader.ps) by Vatne (only in PostScript).

Comment: Have you actually looked inside the book of Loday and Vallette? It is a large book, but if you know some stuff about associative algebras, many things can be skipped, and it is too well written to not be enjoyable. The "Leitfaden" included there (and reproduced on the webpage http://math.unice.fr/~brunov/Operads.html) would be very helpful to navigate.

Answer (score 9):

[Benoit Fresse's book *Modules over Operads and Functors*](http://math.univ-lille1.fr/~fresse/OperadModuleFunctors-Updated.pdf) is masterful.

Additionally, here are a couple of very good survey articles and notes from conferences:

[AMS "What is..." article written by Stasheff](http://www.ams.org/notices/200406/what-is.pdf)

[Expository article by Shenghao Sun](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.180.1723&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

[Notes from Algebra, Topology, and Fjords Conference](http://math.berkeley.edu/~aaron/atf/)

Answer (score 6):

The book of Markl, Stasheff and Shnider is also a standard reference.

Also, a good jumping-in point could be Ginzburg and Kapranov's "Koszul duality for operads".

Comment: I prefer the MSS book above the rest of references because it treats operads in many contexts. Other sources concentrate in linear operads, or some other specific kinds of operads. That book is not perfect, but it is the best available starting point.

Comment: Except of course that the actual definition of operads it gives is incorrect.  A crucial equivariance formula is missing.  The request is for something concise. There are two brief introductions to operads in general categories on http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/PAPERSMaster.html, numbers [84] and [85].

Comment: The MSS book is great, but some parts of it feel written hastily. Maybe it feels that way because in some 10 years since it was written, many things about operads were spelled out in a much cleaner way, like in Loday--Vallette.

Answer (score 2):

Since both the following references appeared significantly later than the OP, it seems useful to add:

- [Donald Yau: *Colored Operads*. AMS. Graduate Studies in Mathematics
  Volume 170](http://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-170/)
- The review of the above book written by Nick Gurski in the most recent issue (September 2017) of the [Jahresbericht der deutschen Mathematiker-Vereinigung](https://www.springerprofessional.de/jahresbericht-der-deutschen-mathematiker-vereinigung/4966776)

Answer (score 2):

The book by M. Bremner and V. Dotsenko titled *Algebraic Operads: an algorithmic companion* (published in 2016) is (in my perhaps biased opinion) a must-have for those wishing to complement their reading of Loday--Vallette. As the authors explain :

> It is fairly accurate to say that the aim of this book is to create an
> accessible companion book to [180] which would, in the spirit of [64] contain enough hands-on methods for working with specific operads: making experiments, formulating conjectures and, hopefully, proving theorems, as well as, in the spirit of [252], include enough interesting examples to stimulate the reader toward those experiments, conjectures and theorems.

As the back-matter explains, it contains a systematic treatment of Groebner bases in several contexts, starting with non-commutative polynomials, and then moving to richer structure like twisted and shuffle algebras, and operads (ns, shuffle, symmetric), the main topic of the book. Like the book of Loday--Vallette, many instances of the book record relatively recent results concerning operads and related structures, and at the same time provides the reader with many challenging exercises (sometimes prompting them to use a CAS, if necessary) that provide invaluable insight for those aiming to make concrete computations using rewriting systems and their kin to study and prove results about operads.

[64] is *Ideals, Varieties and Algorithms* by Cox, Little and O'Shea,
[180] is *Algebraic Operads* by Loday and Vallette and
[252] is *Combinatorial and Asymptotic Methods in Algebra* by Ufnarovski.

Answer (score 0):

A recent good book is [Algebraic Operads by Jean-Louis Loday and Bruno Vallette](http://www-irma.u-strasbg.fr/~loday/PAPERS/LodayVallette.pdf).

Comment: I've mentioned this book in my question. It really is a good book, but it's too big to read it as a quick introduction. But thank you for the link!

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice that you know already Loday-Valette's book !

Comment: Next September 4-6 (2013), I shall attend the meeting on "The Mathematical Legacy of Jean-Louis Loday" here in Strasbourg. In case I'll come across something interesting for you (as you ask), I'll signal it to you.

Comment: Just now, I attended Vladimir Dotsenko' talk : "Beyond quadratic operads". It was excellent; very clear, giving essential keys and links for understanding . He showed how Gröbner bases are a powerful tool to deal whith operads. See his homepage; he is a MathOverflow user.Ask him copies of his (general) talks on the subject (many meetings).